# Submitting my form with Ajax only saving half the data from the dynamic inputs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, dynamicform

I'm in the middle of finishing a page to edit your profile and settings. To save the data from the dynamic inputs, I used Ajax to transfer the data to the server, which then stores the data in a dictionary, into the Session, as well as the name of the menu you would like to save. 
After that, I call a post back with JavaScript. 
In c# on the page load, if it is a post back it will call the SaveData function, which checks the Session for the menu name that you would like to save, and will call the right function accordingly(SaveProfile, SaveNotifications, SavePrivacy, ect..).

My problem is its only saving half of the data from the Dynamic Inputs.
There is 6 different lists that have dynamic inputs, 3 are just a plain Text Input, the other 3 have a Select with a Text Input.
The ones that get saved are totally random, sometimes it will only save social links, sometimes it will only save skills, and you get the idea.

I think its happening because Ajax functions are asynchronous, and when the post back is triggered, not all the data was saved to the session.

There is too much code to post all of it, so if you want to see other stuff just tell me what you would like to see.

Creating the onclick save events.

```js
 var dynamicListIds = ["skills", "hobbies", "games"];
        var dynamicSelectListIds = ["socialLinks", "contactInfo", "systemSpecs"];

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("a[save=all]").on('click', function () { MultipleDataPassToServer(dynamicListIds, dynamicSelectListIds, 'all'); });
            $("a[save=profile]").on('click', function () { MultipleDataPassToServer(dynamicListIds, dynamicSelectListIds, $(this).attr('save')); });
            $("a[save][save!=all][save!=profile]").on('click', function () { CallDataPassedEvent($(this).attr('save')); });
        });
```

Collecting and transferring data.

```js
//Begins the procedure of collection and passing data to the server.
function MultipleDataPassToServer(listIDs, selectListIDs, save) {

    if (listIDs != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < listIDs.length; i++) {
            TransferInputDataToHiddenField(listIDs[i]);
        }
    }
    if (selectListIDs != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < selectListIDs.length; i++) {
            TransferSelectInputDataToHiddenField(selectListIDs[i]);
        }
    }
    CallDataPassedEvent(save);
}







//Gets all values from input elements,
//combines them into one string
//and passes the data to the server
function TransferInputDataToHiddenField(id)
{
    var inputElements =  document.getElementsByName("input" + id);
    //var inputElements = $('#input'  + id);

    var inputValues = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++)
    {
        inputValues += inputElements[i].value;

        if (i != inputElements.length - 1)
        {
            inputValues += "|";
        }
    }

    CallPassDataToServer(id, inputValues);
}


//Gets all values from select and input elements,
//combines them into one string
//and passes the data to the server
function TransferSelectInputDataToHiddenField(id) {
    var inputElements = document.getElementsByName("input" + id);
    var selectElements = document.getElementsByName("select" + id);
    //var inputElements = $('#input'  + id);

    var inputValues = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++) {

        if ($(selectElements[i]).val() == "Custom") {
            inputValues += $('#' + id + "Custom" + i).val() + "=";
        }
        else
        {
            inputValues += selectElements[i].value + "=";           
        }

       
        inputValues += inputElements[i].value;

        if (i != inputElements.length - 1) {
            inputValues += "|";
        }
    }

    CallPassDataToServer(id, inputValues);
}




//Passes data asynchronously to the server
function CallPassDataToServer(id, clientData) {
    PageMethods.PassDataToServer(id, clientData, onSucceeded, onFailed);
}


//Calls event to tell server that either the data has been passed,
//or no data needs to be passed.
//save is a string which tells the server which forms's data will be saved.
//pass 'all' into save for the server to save all forms.
function CallDataPassedEvent(save)
{
    PageMethods.CallEventDataPassed(save, onDataPassed, onFailed);
}

function onDataPassed(result, userContext, methodName) {
        __doPostBack();
}
```

C# Server Code

```cs
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
    public static string PassDataToServer(String id, String clientData)
    {
        if (!dynamicInputs.ContainsKey(id))
            dynamicInputs.Add(id, clientData);
        else
            dynamicInputs[id] = clientData;



        return "Debug - Data Passed : " + clientData;
    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
    public static void CallEventDataPassed(String menu)
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["AccountSave"] = menu;
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ProfileDynamicInputs"] = dynamicInputs;

        //I tried calling the postback from here but it just gives me an error client side. (OnFailed)
        //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
        //EventDataPassed(menu);        
    }
```

C# OnLoad

```cs
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            SaveData((string)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["AccountSave"]);
        }
    }


    [UserAction.Authorize.Account]
    [UserAction.Authorize.Restrictions(UserAction.Authorize.AuthorizationRule.RequireAll, new int[] { 2, 11 }, true)]
    protected void SaveData(string menu)
    {

        switch (menu)
        {
            case "all":
                SaveProfileData();
                break;
            case "profile":
                SaveProfileData();
                break;
            case "billing":
                break;
            case "privacy":
                break;
            case "notifications":
                break;
            case "account":
                break;
        }
    }
```

[Here is an image of the site,](https://s9.postimg.org/wbwhqfsfj/dynamic_Input_Lists.png) knowing what something looks like helps me think.
After I save only some of the options will still be there, seemingly random ones, and if I save again, more disappear, if not all of them.

Every time the page loads, it recreates the dynamic inputs with c#, if you need to see that just ask.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using AJAX if you are making a trip to save the data eventually? Why do you not do the whole operation in the postback without using session variables?

Comment: Because I'm creating the dynamic lists with javascript, and I was having trouble grabbing the data with Request.Form["dynamicID"]. It kept giving me an error, so I thought this would be a better way.